# Array index out of bounds?

Tags: java, eclipse

This method should determine whether the game is over or not initially and after some moves.

```
public boolean isGameOver() {
    Point[] player1 = new Point[12];
    int p1 = 0;
    Point[] player2 = new Point[12];
    int p2 = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
            if (board[i][j] == 1) {
                Point p = new Point(i, j);
                player1[p1] = p;
                p1++;
                //System.out.println(p.getX()+ " 1 " + p.getY());
            } else if (board[i][j] == 2) {
                Point p = new Point(i, j);
                player2[p2] = p;
                p2++;
                //System.out.println(p.getX()+ " 2 " + p.getY());
            }
        }
    }
    for(int i1=0;i1<player1.length;i1++) {
        ArrayList<Point> temp = getPossibleMoves(player1[i1]);
        if(temp.isEmpty())
            return true;
    }
    for(int i1=0;i1<player1.length;i1++) {
        ArrayList<Point> temp = getPossibleMoves(player2[i1]);
        if(temp.isEmpty())
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

The problem is when i run those tests they both have an error of array index out of bounds 
Those are the tests

initially:

```
  @Test(timeout=1000)
public void testGameOverInitial() {
    assertFalse(board.isGameOver());
}
```

after some moves:

```
 @Test(timeout=1000)

public void testGameOverAfterSomeMoves() {
    board.move(new Point(1, 0), new Point(3, 2)); // White's turn
    board.move(new Point(0, 5), new Point(2, 5)); // Black's turn
    assertFalse(board.isGameOver());
}
```

Comment: Where is the error?  If I'm reading this right, it'd be on one of the accesses to `board[i][j]`, which we don't see initialized.

Comment: @PaulProgrammer ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException, as stated in title.

Comment: Yes, but at what line?  My question was WHERE, not WHAT

Comment: Was hoping to get the answer from OP, to teach him how to read stack traces and do his own research in the future.

Comment: @PaulProgrammer you can do that in an answer :).

Comment: @user2246674 I can only say, similar problems happen in other tags as well. Still, we're here to help OP with comments or answers. AFAIK I tend to answer these questions in comments but then somebody else post an answer (that is easier to read). Next time, instead of arguing or rant about this behavior, you can post an answer too or add a post in http://meta.stackoverflow.com/ about this.

Comment: @user2246674 I did, and replied as well :).

Comment: thank you all guys am sorry i'll try to be more specific in the future its just i hate java and i don't quite understand it but i really appreciate your responses :D

Comment: @Andrew92 do not hate Java otherwise it would be bitter to affront new problems. By the way, this problem can happen on other programming languages as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `p1` and `p2` are nested in `for` loops, they can increase up to 49 instead of 12 that is the size of both of your player arrays.

You can either check the length of `p1` if it is smaller than `player1.length` like @LuiggiMendoza suggests. Or you can fix your loop and the length of you you `player` arrays.

I'm not sure what you are trying to do. You need to pick the best solution for the problem you are trying to solve.

Answer (score 1):

You're not controlling the value of `p1` and `p2` variables, so they can be greater than your array length.

Lines with the error:

```
player1[p1]
p1++;

player2[p2]
p2++;
```

A possible solution would be to control when you increase the values of these variables:

```
//similar for player2 and p2
if (p1 < player1.length) {
    p1++;
}
```